# Recyclerview not work with notifyItemRemoved when sqliteDatabse operation is perform

Tags: android

I am using swipe to remove the item from the SQLite database, Item remove from the database but `notifyItemRemoved()` function does not work with `RecyclerView`, it displays blank space in at the position of the remove item.

```
mDatabaseHelper.open();
mDatabaseHelper.deleteSubCartItems(data.get(position).getActivityId());
mDatabaseHelper.deleteMyCartItem(data.get(position).getActivityId());
mDatabaseHelper.close();
this.data.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
```

Comment: Add sufficient code . Your question is not clear enough .

Comment: Have you removed that item from your collection array?

Comment: Yes, I remove the item from the collection array.Data is my collection array

Comment: Code is like this

Comment: @KishanThakar have a look at answer.!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is , perform 3 steps.!

instead of `getItemCount()` pass `data.size()`;

```
                data.remove(position); //removing data from collection
                notifyItemRemoved(position); //notifying item is removed at a given index
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size()); //notifying range is change
```

comment these lines mentioned below and run these 4 lines mentioned above.!

```
// mDatabaseHelper.open();

  //  mDatabaseHelper.deleteSubCartItems(data.get(position).getActivityId());

  //  mDatabaseHelper.deleteMyCartItem(data.get(position).getActivityId());

  //  mDatabaseHelper.close();
```

if it works fine then there is issue with your database query and share LOG as well.!

Comment: try this now , try data.size() instead of getItemCount() try writing this code before removing data from database.if it works fine then there is issue with your delete query.!

Comment: @AntonKazakov are not its right way.? to delete object  from collection .?

Comment: I mean what the point of notifying some items using fast methods like notifyItemRemoved and then calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @KishanThakar are you sure you are removing data from right collection.?